# Alignment of 'vmatrix' environments in an 'align*' environment

Tags: align, amsmath

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        &\[\begin{vmatrix}
            \dfrac{p}{x^3}-\dfrac{3z}{x^4} & -\dfrac{y}{x^2} \\
            \dfrac{q}{x^3} & \dfrac{1}{x}
        \end{vmatrix}=0
        \]
        \\
        \Longrightarrow\;&\[\begin{vmatrix}
            px-3z & -y \\
            qx & x \\
        \end{vmatrix}=0
        \]
        \\
        \Longrightarrow\; &p+qx=3z
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I want to align the lines but it's all messed up. I cannot figure out what `bad environment delimiter` is there.

Comment: Do not use `\[` and `\]` when already in math mode (align*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get rid of the "bad math environment delimiter" messages, you must get rid of both instances of `\[` and `\]` that currently encase the `vmatrix` environments.

I would also employ the `booktabs` package and its `\addlinespace` macro to create more vertical whitespace between the rows of the `vmatrix` environments and between rows of the `align*` environment.

Optionally, you could employ `\phantom{-}` directives in the (2,2) cells to tweak the horizontal alignment of the cell contents relative to the contents of the (1,2) cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs} % <-- new
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    &\begin{vmatrix}
       \dfrac{p}{x^3}-\dfrac{3z}{x^4} & -\dfrac{y}{x^2} \\ 
       \addlinespace
       \dfrac{q}{x^3} & \phantom{-}\dfrac{1}{x}
    \end{vmatrix}=0 \\ 
    \addlinespace
    \Longrightarrow
    &\begin{vmatrix}
       px-3z & -y \\ 
       \addlinespace
       qx    & \phantom{-}x \\
    \end{vmatrix}=0 \\
    \Longrightarrow 
    &\kern3pt  p+qx=3z
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really liked the use of `\phantom{-}` just to align the `y` and `x`. Also the idea of `\addlinespace` is quite brilliant. Nothing but just to make the document more eye soothing. Just one question. Is `\kern` same as `\hskip`?

Comment: @ManjoyDas - They're almost the same -- \hspace` adds breakable whitespace whereas `\kern` adds unbreakable whitespace. Also, the argument of `\hspace` should be enclosed in curly braces; in contrast, the argument of `\kern` must not be delimited with curly braces.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the description `Optionally, you could employ \vphantom{-} directives` that you made. Shouldn't it be `\phantom{-} ` for horizontal tweak?

Comment: @ManjoyDas -- Good catch! Let me fix that. (In my own papers, I only ever use `\vphantom`, not `\phantom` -- I guess "muscle memory" showed through for a moment...)